# How can I change the color of a polyline in here.com javascript-api?

Tags: javascript, gis, here-api

I have multiple polylines drawn in a map, I would like them to change their color of depending on some event... Is there a function to change the strokecolor property once the polyline object has been added to the map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `setStyle`-method:

```
polyline.setStyle( polyline.getStyle().getCopy({strokeColor:'Red'}));
```

The `getCopy`-method returns a copy of the given SpatialStyle where the properties of the argument(`{strokeColor:'Red'}`) replace the properties of the given SpatialStyle